# Show/Hide based on Dropdown selection in knockoutJS with model inside another model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, formbuilder

I am working on "Rules" for form builder.

I want to show/hide text box based on the dropdown selected.

For example, let us assume we have a following "Rules" for a "TextField" control under "Form Builder"

```
Rule#   Control(dropdown)          Condition(dropdown)          Value(as input textbox)

1       TextBox_1                    Is filled out             (Text Input NOT REQUIRED)

2       TextBox_2                        Contains                         Hi
```

From the above, for Rule 1, the text input is not required and for Rule 2, Text Input is required.

The above is my scenario.

**What I tried:**

**HTML content:**

```
 //Dropdown for "Condition"

  <select 
          class="form-control" 
          data-bind="
                     value: selectedValue
                     options: ruleConditions().options(),
                     optionsText: 'Name', 
                     optionsValue: 'Value',
                     optionsCaption: 'Choose condition'">
  </select>


 //Input text field for "Value"

<input 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      data-bind="visible: ruleConditions().selectedValue()" />
```

**KnockoutJS Content:**

I have two view Models.

`1) FormViewModel`

`2) TextBoxViewModel`

Also, I have one array which contains `options` for the dropdown.

**And my implementation are as follows:**

```
//Options Available in Array

var RuleConditionArray = {

// Options for "Text Field" under Rules tab

textFieldConditions: ko.observableArray
         (
           [
             { 
               Name: 'is filled out', 
               Value: 'isfilledout', 
               isExpressionValueRequired: false 
             },

             {
               Name: 'contains', 
               Value: 'contains', 
               isExpressionValueRequired: true
             }
           ]
        )
};

//Form View Model
function FormVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.textBoxVM = ko.observable(new TextBoxViewModel(Id,Name));
}

//TextField View Model
function TextBoxViewModel(Id, Name) {
var Txt = this;

Txt.CommonProperties = new CommonViewModel(Id, Name);

// Initialize Rule Conditions from Array.
Txt.ruleConditions = ko.observable(new RuleConditionViewModel(RuleConditionArray.textFieldConditions()));

Txt.selectedItem = ko.observable();

Txt.selectedValue = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.selectedItem() && this.selectedItem().isExpressionValueRequired
}, this);

}

formView = new FormVM();
ko.applyBindings(formView);
```

**What I get:**

From the above code, I am able to populate the dropdown with values.

**What I did not get:**

I am unable to `show/hide` `Value` text input field for "Rules". I need to get the value of `isExpressionValueRequired` and show/hide "`Value`" input text field  based on this value.

I am struck with this. Kindly help me to get rid off this.

**Edit - 1 : My Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/vikash208/z4x5meua/3/

Comment: Aren't you missing a `value: selectedItem` data-bind in your `<select>` element?

Comment: I tried it. But doesn't work. I have tried with different solutions from `StackOverflow` and `jsFiddle`. For example, I tried this solution in jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AZ9Cn/) , which best _suits my approach_ but _not my scenario_.@user3297291

Comment: Could you increase the points so that, many users can see this question and get resolved quickly?

Comment: Best way to get a quick answer is usually to create a fiddle or stack snippet that has enough code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll create and let you about the fiddle shortly.

Comment: I created the fiddle and updated in my question as Edit -1 which is present at the bottom of the question. Please find it. @user3297291

Comment: Is it supposed to work like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hxchstp9/ ? If it is, I'll write up an answer to explain what wan't working.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Thank you so much. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems in your code:

- The visible binding: `selectedValue` is a property in `TextBoxViewModel`, *not* in `RuleConditionViewModel`. Therefore, `visible: ruleConditions().selectedValue()` should only be `visible: selectedValue`
- The `optionsValue: 'Value'` binding tells knockout to only store the `Value` property of a rule condition. I.e.: it stores the string `isfilledout` or `contains`. Remove it, and the whole object is stored.
- Because the `selectedItem` was a string, the computed expression `this.selectedItem() && this.selectedItem().isExpressionValueRequired` was always false: the `string` prototype does not have a property named `isExpressionValueRequired`.

https://jsfiddle.net/hxchstp9/

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I have a question. How can I map the selected value to dropdown which is something like edit options ? @user3297291

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Now If I want to set the values for dropdown through model. I think it is not possible with `value` in `data-bind` .  Because, we are storing the whole object under `value`

Comment: You'll have to set it to one of the objects in `ruleConditions().options()`. For example: `Txt.selectedItem(ruleConditions().options()[0])`

Comment: I am working on it. Once I complete, I will update you whether I get the solution or not. Thanks man. Great help.

Comment: Unable to populate the value in dropdown with default value. Here is my fiddle trying to populate the value on load with RuleConditionArray[0]. [link]https://jsfiddle.net/vikash208/uawcgo6f/1/ . Also, I have a question, What If I saved without choosing the data ? It throws error, when I save the data without choosing anything.

Comment: You create a viewmodel per option, so you'll have to select the viewmodel: `Txt.selectedItem = ko.observable(Txt.ruleConditions().options()[0]);` (https://jsfiddle.net/usa9h1Ls/)

Comment: But I have a question, What If I saved without choosing the data ?My scenario is, Now I save the data without choosing anything. After saving, it knockouJS throws error says that "Unable to bind Message: selectedItem is not defined" . What does it mean ?

Comment: Saving a viewmodel to JSON and reloading it is a whole different topic. Have a look at the ko.mapping plugin. If you run in to any specific problems, ask a new question. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you buddy. I'll come up with different topic.

Comment: Hi. Here is my fiddle [link]https://jsfiddle.net/vikash208/6b6ntoam/19/ . Trying to select the dropdown using selectedCondition. But not working. This is my actual model which I am using in my application.