# Fill dropdown values from data-bind="selectedValue" in knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, formbuilder

I am working on "Form Builder" application, where I can set the rules for each control.

I am trying to select the dropdown value from `selectedValue` which I kept as object. But it is not working.

To understand my question in depth, here is my previous question where you get the clear understanding of my question :

[Show/Hide based on Dropdown selection in knockoutJS with model inside another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255895/show-hide-based-on-dropdown-selection-in-knockoutjs-with-model-inside-another-mo)

Here is my fiddle which I worked out for filling the dropdown values(Current question) :

https://jsfiddle.net/vikash208/6b6ntoam/20/

**What I tried :**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="tab-content" data-bind="with: TextBoxModel">
<div class="tab-pane" id="rules" data-bind="with: rules">
                                    <div data-bind="foreach: ruleList">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.ruleConditions, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedCondition, optionsCaption: 'Choose condition'"></select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-5" data-bind="visible: isExpressionValueRequired()">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: expressionValue" />
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

**KnockoutJS of assigning selectedOption:**

```
var RuleConditionArray = {
  // Options for "Text Field" under Rules tab
    textField: ko.observableArray(
    [
    { Name: 'is filled out', 
      Value: 'isfilledout',
      isExpressionValueRequired: false 
    },

    { 
      Name: 'is not filled out', 
      Value: 'isnotfilledout', 
      isExpressionValueRequired: true 
    }
   ]
 )
};

function Rule() {
    var rule = this;

    //For Expression input field
    rule.expressionValue = ko.observable("");

    //Keep track of selected ruleConditions - returns "Condition object"
     rule.selectedCondition = ko.observable({ Name: 'is filled out', Value: 'isfilledout', isExpressionValueRequired: false });

    //This is computed value to show/hide Expression input field
    rule.isExpressionValueRequired = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.selectedCondition() &&     this.selectedCondition().isExpressionValueRequired
    }, this);
};
```

From the above knockoutJS code, I am passing

```
    { 
      Name: 'is filled out', 
      Value: 'isfilledout',
      isExpressionValueRequired: false 
    }
```

object inside `selectedCondition`. But it is not working.

**What I want:**

I need to pass object as parameter to select the dropdown Value. Kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<select>` element has an array of options passed to it by the `options` binding. Each option represents an instance of an object. When you select an option, the `value` binding makes sure the object is written to `selectedCondition`.

The other way around, when you set your `selectedCondition`, knockout looks within the array of options to see if it's an option that's already known. If it can find it, it will update the UI.

Now, **the problem here**, is that you're setting the `selectedCondition` to an object that *looks the same* as one of the options, but is not one of the actual option instances.

Knockout doesn't use a (deep) object comparison method for looking up the selected object, it just does something along the lines of: `options.indexOf(newSelection)`. Since you've created a *new* object, this won't work.

### Solution

Pass an actual reference to the `selectedCondition`, like so:

```
rule.selectedCondition = ko.observable(ruleModel.ruleConditions()[0]);
```

If you want to add a new option, push it to the `options` first:

```
var newOption = { 
  Name: ko.observable(""), 
  Value: ko.observable(""), 
  isExpressionValueRequired: ko.observable(false) 
};

ruleModel.ruleConditions.push(newOption);
selectedCondition(newOption);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll update the working fiddle shortly.